# how to use @StringDef in an app with i18n

Tags: java, android, internationalization, android-support-library

`@StringDef` is great for replacing `Enum`.

```
@StringDef(Standard, Mini)
public @interface Type;
```

But what if my app needs to support english, french and chinese?

So the standard might be "Standard", "Norme", and "标准" in three different countries. In that case, the Standard and Mini may need the context to get the real value.

How could we still use `@StringDef` in an app with i18n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box solution.

The recommended way is to store localized string resources in different directories (`res/values-XX/strings.xml`, where `XX` is `en`, `fr` etc).

> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

In this approach you need to use string id to get the localized string. You can try the following:

1. Use ids of strings instead:

   ```
   @IntDef({R.string.standard, R.string.mini})
   ```
2. Use some helper to match `@StringDef`'s string to localized string resorce.
3. Use enums.

Comment: About the solution 2, I don't understand well. Could you please explain it more?

And the first solution is great !

Comment: #2 - I ment you can write some util `StringHelper` to match `@StringDef` items to `R.string.xxx` resources, using `switch` or something similar. It's not preferred, but possible option :)